# Remove margin and padding dynamically WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, layout

I am currently doing a page with a form in it in WPF. There are two textboxes and one listbox with a button to add some elements in the listbox. In one mode (edit mode), I want everything to be visible so that the user will be able to edit the textboxes and add elements in the listbox. In the other mode (view mode), I binded the Visibility property so that when in this mode, everything except the listbox appears (and the listbox takes the whole place) so that the user can just see what existing elements are in the listbox.

Now my problem is, in the edit mode I give a Margin="10" margin, but in view mode I would like the listbox to take the full page width/height (so I would like to remove that margin). How would I go to do this?

My XAML (some user controls are encapsulated in a framework that I am using, but it shouldn't affect my question):

```
<Grid x:Name="MainScope" pres:OneTheme.Theme="Content">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="53*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <pres:OneContentLayout Mode="List" Grid.Row="3"  Margin="10" >
    <pres:OneListBox x:Name="ListBox" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Presentation_ControlBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding InterfaceSpecification.IOPoints}"
                     DeleteItemRequestCommand="{Binding DeleteIOPointCommand}" IsEdited="{Binding IsEditable}" >
            <pres:OneListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <vw:IOPointDefinitionView Grid.Column="0" />
                            <vw:IOPointOtherConnectedElementView Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,0"/>

                            <pres:OneIcon Grid.Column="2" IconBrush="{DynamicResource Icon_DraggableHandleHorizontal}" Margin="8,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ListBox, Path=IsEdited, Converter={StaticResource OneBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

                            </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </pres:OneListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </pres:OneListBox>
    </pres:OneContentLayout>
    <pres:OneTextBox Watermark="Name..." Text="{Binding InterfaceSpecification.Name}" Margin="85,12,0,0"
                     AcceptsReturn="False" MaxLines="1" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" Visibility="{Binding IsEditable, Converter={StaticResource OneBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <pres:OneTextBox Margin="85,3.999,10,3" Text="{Binding InterfaceSpecification.Description}"
                     Watermark="Description..." Height="66" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding IsEditable, Converter={StaticResource OneBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

    <pres:OneToggleButton x:Name="Add_Button" Content="Add IO Point" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Row="2" Width="115" Height="18"
                          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=Add_Popover, Path=IsOpen}"
                          pres:OneTheme.PresentationMode="Inline" Visibility="{Binding IsEditable, Converter={StaticResource OneBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
...
```

Comment: Post your XAML.  Use a Grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you basically want `pres:OneContentLayout` to have a margin of 0 when `IsEditable` is false and 10 when it's true, right?

You can use a `Trigger` in a `Style` to make that work like this:

```
<pres:OneContentLayout.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type pres:OneContentLayout}">

        <!-- Default margin is 0 -->
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- When in edit-mode make margin 10 -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</pres:OneContentLayout.Style>
```

Comment: Perfect answer! The only thing I needed to modify is to apply the style to pres:OneContentLayout instead of the listbox, as that is what had the margin. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Have fixed the type in the answer. Glad it worked.